# Trouble compiling tensorflow lite file to work on coral tpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tpu

I'm trying to get repetitively simple model to compile so that it will run on the coral tpu. I've so far frozen and converted the file to a tflite file, however when I run the file through the Edge [TPU Model Compiler](https://coral.withgoogle.com/web-compiler/) it gives me a relatively unhelpful error message.

```
COMPILING FAILED
Something went wrong. Couldn't compile model.
Please make sure your model meets the requirements.
See the log below for more compilation details.
If you believe your model meets the requirements but you still receive this error,
email support at coral‑support@google.com.
```

I emailed them and they said to use the /tensorflow/lite/tools:visualize to see what is wrong with the model. (I'm having trouble getting that to work as well but that seems like I should ask a seperate question to get help with the bazel stuff)

I have trained the model with quantization aware training following [this site](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/quantize#quantization-aware-training) and I have run the tflite file with random inputs and it seems to work. I was worried that part of the issue with the TPU model compiler was that I was behind a proxy so I ran someone else's file through it and it successfully compiled.)

Here is the eval graph:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.tools import inspect_checkpoint as chkp
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


#test data
seed = np.random.seed(141)

features = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], sep=',', index_col=0)
labels = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[2], sep=',', index_col=0)
train_input, test_input, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)

def neuron_layer(X, n_neurons, name, activation=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        n_inputs = int(X.get_shape()[1])
        W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_inputs, n_neurons]), name="kernal")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_neurons]), name="bias")
        Z = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
        if activation is not None:
            return activation(Z)
        else:
            return Z

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, 701), name="X")
n_outputs = 2
n_hidden1 = 700
n_hidden2 = 701
with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden1 = neuron_layer(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # hidden2 = neuron_layer(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # trying only one layer
    logits = neuron_layer(hidden1, n_outputs, name="outputs")

with tf.name_scope("final_eval"):
    output = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1, name="output")


# Call the eval rewrite which rewrites the graph in-place with
# FakeQuantization nodes and fold batchnorm for eval.
g = tf.get_default_graph()
tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph(input_graph=g)

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()
eval_graph_file = "eval_graph.pb"

#handles different tensorboard runs
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
root_logdir = "tf_logs"
logdir = "eval/{}/run-{}".format(root_logdir, now)

file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir, tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "./nbtf/nothing_but_tf_model.ckpt")

    # Save the checkpoint and eval graph proto to disk for freezing
    # and providing to TFLite.
    with open(eval_graph_file, 'w+') as f:
        f.write(str(g.as_graph_def()))
    saver.save(sess, "./nbtf/eval/eval.ckpt")
    pred = output.eval(feed_dict={X: [test_input.values[45]]})
    print(pred, test_labels.values[45])
```

Then I freeze with this:

```
 freeze_graph --input_graph=eval_graph.pb --input_checkpoint=nbtf\eval\eval.ckpt --output_graph=frozen_eval_graph.pb --output_node_names=final_eval/output
```

Then convert with this:

```
toco --graph_def_file=frozen_eval_graph.pb --output_file=tflite_model.tflite --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --input_array=X --output_array=final_eval/output --std_dev_value=127 --mean_value=127
```

[tensorboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCdA6.png)

I'm just wanting this file to compile it doesn't have to be perfect or anything.

Thank you for the help.

Edit:

I've tried two things the first is that I printed out the tensors from the tflite file (I was trying to use the visualize.py tool but I was behind a proxy and having a lot of trouble getting it to work.) I got this:

```
{'name': 'X', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 701]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.007874015718698502, 127)}
{'name': 'dnn/fully_connected/MatMul_bias', 'index': 1, 'shape': array([702]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.int32'>, 'quantization': (3.750092218979262e-05, 0)}
{'name': 'dnn/fully_connected/Relu', 'index': 2, 'shape': array([  1, 702]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.035464514046907425, 0)}
{'name': 'dnn/fully_connected/weights_quant/FakeQuantWithMinMaxVars/transpose', 'index': 3, 'shape': array([702, 701]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.004762616939842701, 121)}
{'name': 'dnn/fully_connected_1/MatMul_bias', 'index': 4, 'shape': array([703]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.int32'>, 'quantization': (0.0001283923047594726, 0)}
{'name': 'dnn/fully_connected_1/Relu', 'index': 5, 'shape': array([  1, 703]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.019155390560626984, 0)}
{'name': 'dnn/fully_connected_1/weights_quant/FakeQuantWithMinMaxVars/transpose', 'index': 6, 'shape': array([703, 702]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.0036203034687787294, 120)}
{'name': 'dnn/outputs/MatMul_bias', 'index': 7, 'shape': array([2]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.int32'>, 'quantization': (3.3737978810677305e-05, 0)}
{'name': 'dnn/outputs/add', 'index': 8, 'shape': array([1, 2]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.055008530616760254, 131)}
{'name': 'dnn/outputs/weights_quant/FakeQuantWithMinMaxVars/transpose', 'index': 9, 'shape': array([  2, 703]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.0017612784868106246, 110)}
{'name': 'final_eval/output', 'index': 10, 'shape': array([1, 1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.int64'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}
{'name': 'final_eval/output/dimension', 'index': 11, 'shape': array([], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.int32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}
```

I think the issue is that the MatMul_bias tensors are not being converted to uint8 (which the coral tpu requires).

I'm not sure how to fix that.

The other change I tried is using tensorflow slim.fully_connected as opposed to my own custom fully connected neural network. (They have the same issue though.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to compile the file no problem I just had to use the [offline compiler](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/compiler/). Seemed to fix it entirely.